# Check if a column is float

Tags: awk

I have a requirement that i want to check if a column is float or not. If its a float then do nothing else concatenate with `.00`.

File:

```
2017 47.0000 0.783333 0.2500
1663 1920.0000 32 8.0000
```

Expected output:

```
2017 47.0000 0.783333 0.2500
1663 1920.0000 32.00 8.0000
```

Command:

```
awk -F" " '{if ($9=="^[0-9]") {print  $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$7$8} else {print  $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$7}}' | head -1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$3 !~ /\./ { sub($3, $3 ".00") } { print }' columns
```

This suggestion is based on the sample input, obviously. It works as follows: if column three (the code in the OP uses column nine, but the sample input isn't that long) does not contain a literal dot, replace column three with column three plus the literal string `.00` (in other words: append the string to the column). Then print the line, whether it matched or not. This command is abbreviated as `1` by some users, but I find that a bit too cryptic.

Note that this solution is unsafe, since it uses string substitution rather than substituting the column itself.

Comment: 4-30-16 4-30-16 917878805527 9132958962504601 1663 1920.0000 32 8.0000

Comment: @Anurag You might want to clarify what you want.  For example, in the question, `4-30-16` does not appear in the sample input.

Comment: If you're going to post an answer like that, you should explain how it works.  This site isn't meant to be a dumping ground for mysterious commands and unexplained script fragments, it's meant to be a resource where people can learn not only HOW to do something but WHAT they're doing and WHY they're doing it.   BTW, writing detailed explanations will help you too - I still learn a lot just from taking the time to explain what i'm doing in plain english.  It's a very effective way to put your thoughts and knowledge in good order.

Comment: @cas Fair enough. I'm still learning the etiquette.

Answer (score 0):

This looks for integers in any column after the first and adds `.00`:

```
$ awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) if (!($i ~ /[.]/))$i=$i ".00"} 1' input
2017 47.0000 0.783333 0.2500
1663 1920.0000 32.00 8.0000
```

#### How it works

- `for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)`

  This starts a loop over the fields, starting with the second field, `i=2`, and continuing on to the last field, `i=NF`.
- `if ( !($i ~ /[.]/))$i=$i ".00"`

  For every `i` that we loop over, we check to see if the i-th field, `$i`, contains a period.  If it does then `($i ~ /[.]/)` evaluates to true.  We, however, negate that result: `!($i ~ /[.]/)` is true only if field `i` does *not* contain period.  If so, we add `.00` to the end of field `i`.

  This `if` statement is the only statement in the `for` loop.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-whole-line.

Comment: Can you please explain the command.

Comment: OK.  I added an explanation.